# Multi-Camera calibration - Stereo Cameras

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, rotational-matrices

I am trying to use calibrate multi-stereo cameras, to get the Rotation and Translation of the camera pose.  For example, how much both the cameras are actually displaced and how much it rotated.

I tried using OpenCV multi-camera calibration class,

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d1c/tutorial_multi_camera_main.html

But I did not see correct Rotation and Translation matrix is retrived.

Other toools I tried vicalib faced integration issue with my camera.

Is there is any references so that I can do head start with Multi-camera calibration.

Comment: Please post a code example of what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

There is a camera calibration method in OpenCV. Here's the c++ method:

C++: double calibrateCamera(InputArrayOfArrays objectPoints, InputArrayOfArrays imagePoints, Size imageSize, InputOutputArray cameraMatrix, InputOutputArray distCoeffs, OutputArrayOfArrays rvecs, OutputArrayOfArrays tvecs, int flags=0, TermCriteria criteria=TermCriteria( TermCriteria::COUNT+TermCriteria::EPS, 30, DBL_EPSILON) )

Source and more docs:
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html

Comment: Individual camera calibration rectifies only the principal point and lens distortion.  What I require is the Transformation of two inde[endent cameras.